# How does the tracing spec define a "vendor"?

Tags: http, http-trace

In [this](https://w3c.github.io/trace-context/#trace-context-http-request-headers-format) specification, the concept of a `vendor` is introduced (own hightlighting):

> The traceparent request header represents the incoming request in a tracing system in a common format, understood by all **vendors**. Here’s an example of a traceparent header. `traceparent: 00-0af7651916cd43dd8448eb211c80319c-b7ad6b7169203331-01`. The tracestate request header includes the parent in a potentially **vendor**-specific format: `tracestate: congo=t61rcWkgMzE`. For example, say a client and server in a system use different tracing **vendors**: Congo and Rojo. A client traced in the Congo system adds the following headers to an outbound HTTP request.

But what's a `vendor` exactly? Is it the name of a service (e.g. `data-retriever`), an identifier for an instance of this service (e.g. `data-retriever-instance123`, or something completely different, like our company's namespace, e.g. `awesomeretrievalsolutions24`, rendering all keys in the `tracestate's` key-value pairs the same when I don't utilize third party services? Or `opentelemetry` (given we use that one), also rendering all keys the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more reading and investigating the OpenTelemetry SDK's logic, I think the answer is:

- The `vendor` is the entity which understands how to read/write/interprete a `statestate`. So, a `vendor` defines the encoding of its `tracestate`. When using OpenTelemetry, the `vendor` is - according to its [documentation](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/trace/tracestate-handling/) - `"ot"`. `p` and `r` in the value are an example of vendor-specific (i.e. OpenTelemetry-specific) implementation/encoding of information (here: [sampling](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/trace/tracestate-probability-sampling) data).
- When adding a new key-value pair to (left-most position) the `tracestate`, any other key-value pair with the same key must be dropped (see the w3c [spec](https://w3c.github.io/trace-context#combined-header-value)).